# How do you call function once pmap has completed in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

In Clojure how can you run a method like pmap and call a function when all items in the collection have been processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap it in a function, that will enforce the mapping and call some callback function after that:

```
user> (defn pmap-callback [callback f & colls]
        (let [res (doall (apply pmap f colls))]
          (callback res)
          res))
#'user/pmap-callback

user> (pmap-callback #(println "complete!" %)
                     + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
;;=> complete! (5 7 9)
(5 7 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`pmap`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pmap) doc string:

> Like map, except f is applied in parallel. Semi-lazy in that the
>   parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption, but doesn't
>   realize the entire result unless required. Only useful for
>   computationally intensive functions where the time of f dominates the
>   coordination overhead.

So the `pmap` result won't be computed completely until you ask for all the elements of the result sequence. As with other lazy sequences you can force the lazy sequence to be fully realized using [`doall`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) (if you need to retain the whole evaluated sequence content) or [`dorun`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) (if you are interested only the side effects done by your mapping function and don't need the evaluated sequence).

To execute a function when all the results have been computed you can just call it directly after the call to `dorun` or `doall`.

It's also worth noting that `pmap` is not a tool to scheduling asynchronous parallel jobs where you could get notified when your processing finishes. For such use cases Clojure [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) might be a better choice.